# The file is in the program because: Root file specified for compilation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Every time I try to compile my code, I keep getting this error, although the casing and spelling is correct.

File name: `'c:/Users/liver/Desktop/Codecademy/React, Part I/Create a Playlist App With the Spotify API (Part One) - Project/create-react-app/Jamming/src/Components/Playlist/Playlist.js'`

Differs from already included file name:
`'c:/Users/liver/Desktop/Codecademy/React, Part I/Create a Playlist App With the Spotify API (Part One) - Project/create-react-app/Jamming/src/Components/PlayList/Playlist.js'` only in casing.

The file is in the program because:
Root file specified for compilation
Imported via `'../Playlist/Playlist'` from file `'c:/Users/liver/Desktop/Codecademy/React, Part I/Create a Playlist App With the Spotify API (Part One) - Project/create-react-app/Jamming/src/Components/App/App.js`'

below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import SearchBar from './SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from './SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   this.state = {
    searchResults: [{name: 'name1', artist: 'artist1', album: 'album1', id: 1}
    , {name: 'name2', artist: 'artist2', album: 'album2', id: 2}, 
    {name: 'name3', artist: 'artist3', album: 'album3', id: 3}],
    PlaylistName: 'My Playlist',
    PlaylistTracks: [{ name: 'playlistName1', artist: 'playlistArtist1', 
    album: 'playlistAlbum1', id: 4 }, {name: 'playlistName2', artist: 'playlistArtist2', album: 'playlistAlbum2', id: 5 },
    {name: 'playlistName3', artist: 'playlistArtist3', album: 'playlistAlbum3', id: 6 }]
   };
   this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  }

addTrack(track) {
let tracks = this.state.PlaylistTracks;
if (tracks.find(savedTrack => savedTrack.id === track.id )) {
  return;
}
 tracks.push(track);
 this.setState({PlaylistTracks: tracks})
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
    <div className="App">
       <SearchBar /> 
      <div className="App-playlist">
       <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} 
                        onAdd ={this.addTrack} />  
        <Playlist PlaylistName={this.state.PlaylistName} 
                  PlaylistTracks={this.state.PlaylistTracks} /> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  )
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: playlist directory]

Ive tried changing the casing at first to a capital from playlist to playList, however after checking my file directory niether the Playlist.js or playlist.css file has any capitalisation in their name

Comment: Please include your code & shows us what you have tried so far. Use [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to build a minimal runnable example.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Im using windows 11 and runnning the code on visual studio

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was solved by changing the name of the file that was causing problems, only with F2 or rename. When you change the file name it automatically redirects the route. At least it worked for me, I hope it works for you too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35708194)

Answer (score 0):

Check the routes on your index.js, where you import App it should have the right route. For example `import App from "./components/App/App"`. You compile through index.js on your main directory.

Answer (score 0):

change your file name to App.jsx instead of App.js.It works for me [image: image 1]

Comment: Give a brief explanation of your response.